# Find lines of integers in 2d array

Tags: arrays

Is there an algorithm to detect lines in 2d arrays? For example

```
1 1 1 1 1 -> horizontal line
0 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1

1 1 1 0 0 -> vertical line
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 1

1 1 1 0 1 -> diagonal line
0 0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 1
```

I am almost sure the solution is somewhere on the surface, but I'm not able to google this correctly.

Comment: What are the constraint given any such?

Comment: @Achy97 array can only contain 0,1 and 2 integers, always 5x5, if I get your question

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"?

Comment: ok then 2 can also be there? and is 11122 a valid line ? @Игорь Быстревский

Comment: @Achy97 no, only the same numbers count. 11111 or 22222

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba to find amount of these lines in array

Comment: the question can be understood in at least six different ways. I think you need a more detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

Since your 2D matrix size is pretty small a `O(n2)` Solution should not affect much, there can be many complex solutions, but I tried to form a very basic solution which traverses the matrix and determines for lines' occurence in different directions

```
n=5 #nXn matrix
ls=[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],[1, 0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
ls2=[[1, 0, 1, 0, 2],[1, 1, 1, 2, 1],[1, 0, 2, 1, 1],[0, 2, 1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 1, 1, 1]]

def checkLine(ls):
    global n
    lines=[]

    #checking for row  lines
    for i in ls:
        if(i.count(1)==n or i.count(2)==n):
            lines.append("Row")

    #checking for column lines        
    for i in range(n):
        #traversing each column
        k1,k2=0,0

        #traversing each row for a particular co;umn
        for j in range(n):
            if ls[j][i]==1:
                k1+=1
            elif ls[j][i]==2:
                k2+=1
        if k1==n or k2==n:
            lines.append("Column")

    #diagonal line check bcause diagonal elements menan ls[i][i]
    k1,k2=0,0
    #top-left to bottom-right diagonal
    for i in range(n):
        if ls[i][i]==1:
                k1+=1
        elif ls[i][i]==2:
            k2+=1
    if k1==n or k2==n:
       lines.append("Diagonal(primary)")

    k1,k2=0,0

    #bottom-left to top-right diagonal
    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
        if ls[n-i-1][i]==1:
                k1+=1
        elif ls[n-i-1][i]==2:
            k2+=1
    if k1==n or k2==n:
        lines.append("Diagonal(seconary)")

    return lines


print(checkLine(ls))
```

And the output for ls1 is `['Row', 'Column', 'Diagonal(primary)', 'Diagonal(seconary)']`

And the output for ls2 is  `['Diagonal(seconary)']`

Check the code here https://onlinegdb.com/rJSnfmlpI

Answer (score 1):

You could use a voting approach, a kind of [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) restricted to horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines.

Here's some Java code to illustrate.

```
int[][] m = {{1,1,1,1,1},{0,1,0,1,1},{0,1,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0},{1,1,0,0,1}};

int n = 5;
int vals = 2;

int[][] rvotes = new int[vals][n];
int[][] cvotes = new int[vals][n];
int[][] dvotes = new int[vals][2];

for(int r=0; r<n; r++)
{
    for(int c=0; c<n; c++)
    {
        if(m[r][c] > 0)
        {
            rvotes[m[r][c]][r]++;
            cvotes[m[r][c]][c]++;
            if(r == c) dvotes[m[r][c]][0]++;
            if(r == n-c-1) dvotes[m[r][c]][1]++;
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then look for "peaks" in the accumulator arrays of size `n`:

```
for(int i=0; i<vals; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(cvotes[i][j] == n) System.out.format("Col %d, Val %d%n", j, i);
        if(rvotes[i][j] == n) System.out.format("Row %d, Val %d%n", j, i);
    }
    if(dvotes[i][0] == n) System.out.format("Diag \\, Val %d%n", i);
    if(dvotes[i][1] == n) System.out.format("Diag /, Val %d%n", i);
}
```

Output:

```
Row 0, Val 1
Col 1, Val 1
Diag \, Val 1
Diag /, Val 1
```